# share variable across script files that use ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, multiprocessing

I am learning and using python 3.6 for my drone programming. I have following scenario to handle:

---

class_A (in Script_A.py) calls a method in class_B(in a different Script_B.py). In class_A, calls to class_B's method is multiprocessed using ProcessPoolExecutor. Each of those processes running the class_B method should write output to something(variable?) which class_A can read even while other processes are still running. 
I do not use database. What are different ways to do it?

---

Though sample code below shows just a integer, in my case I am using cv2 and few other values which cannot be pickled. So it cannot be returned from class_B method in ProcessPoolExecutor world. That is one reason I am not looking to return but write the output somewhere and read it from class_A. Task I am trying to accomplish is to read (multi)processed values derived from camera's video and send commands to drone.

```
Script_A.py
class_A
    ....
    executor.submit(class_B().multiplyValue, value_passed) for 
    value_passed in [1,2,3,4]
    ....

Script_B.py
class_B
    ....
    def multiplyValue(self, value_received):
        new_value = value_received * 2 #This value should be saved and be 
        readable from class_A
    ....
```

Comment: Processes do not share state automatically, and will require pickling regardless of a `return`. You'll likely want to look into various strategies for sharing state across multiple python processes

Comment: Thanks, will search for ways to share state.